# Firebase Xcode Swift - stuck on downloadURL

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I know the downloadURL function has been deprecated, but I can't seem to get the new completion function to work:

```
@IBAction func postButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let mediaFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("media")

    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(postImage.image!, 0.5) {

        mediaFolder.child("\(uuid).jpg").putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                let imageURL = mediaFolder.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error!!!!")
                    } else {
                        return url?.absoluteString
                    }



                })
                print(imageURL)

            }


        })

    }

}
```

I just can't get this to work. I always get the error!!!!! message in the log and I'm not sure why. I've been struggling with this code for the past 3 hours and for some reason I just can't get the imageURL to print.

All I want is to get imageURL to equal url?.absoluteString

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting the URL to print out because you're not querying the right storage references.

First, check if the image is actually uploaded in the storage and then add the child Id to your `mediaFolder` in the `else` statement:

```
 mediaFolder.child("\(uuid).jpg").downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
 })
```

Comment: Thanks. So all I have to do is paste your code into the else statement?

Comment: Yes, test it. But as I said, first make sure that your image has been uploaded successfully

Comment: Thanks Dani! It was uploading correctly the other day, but now I'm getting this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at image. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'